# onTouchEvent for multiple images in view

Tags: java, android

In my Java class we are doing some Android code.
We create a View and pragmatically generate 10 ImageButton (custom button image class with no extensions).
The teacher suggests that we loop through an array containing our 10 ImageButtons to see which ImageButton contains the point of touch (in our onTouchEvent method).
Is there a better way to do this, like for example create an onTouchEvent for the actually ImageButton class?

Comment: How are you programmatically generating buttons? inflating a view? plese provide with some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complicated? Just use a `OnClickListener` for all the buttons and inside the `onClick` method just switch by the id of the clicked view like this:

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case button1.getId():
    break;
    case button2.getId():
    ...
```

Comment: If each of the buttons is extended from `View` it will call `onClick` in the `onClickListener` when touched.